# Парсинг строки в словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, словари

Доброго времени суток.
На входе строка. Ее шаблон: `"{"a": "ex1", "b": "ex2", "c": "ex3"}, {"a": "ex4", "b": "ex5", "c": "ex6"}, ... {"a": "exn-2", "b": "exn-1", "c": "exn"}"`. Мне нужно извлечь в словарь по шаблону `{"a": "ex1", "b": "ex2", "c": "ex3"}`. Пробовал с помошью регулярных выражений - не получилось. Например шаблон "{.+}" возвращал эту же строку. Думал как бы применить split() - тоже головушки не хватило. Прошу навести на правильные мысли.

Comment: что значит "на входе строка"? Если данные уже в переменной `s`, то покажите `print(s)`. То что сейчас показано (`"{"a"`) — это SyntaxError в Питоне.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [1]: from ast import literal_eval as le

In [2]: task = "{'a': 'ex1', 'b': 'ex2', 'c': 'ex3'}"

In [3]: result = le(task)

In [4]: result
Out[4]: {'a': 'ex1', 'b': 'ex2', 'c': 'ex3'}

In [5]: type(result)
Out[5]: dict
```

Comment: попытка вставить шаблон из вопроса в literal_eval к SyntaxError ведёт.

Answer (score 2):

Строка в словарь через `json`-декодер:

```
import json

data = json.loads('{"a": "ex1", "b": "ex2", "c": "ex3"}')
print(type(data), data)
```

Результат:

```
<class 'dict'> {'a': 'ex1', 'b': 'ex2', 'c': 'ex3'}
```

---

Строку в вопросе можно тоже через json обработать, добавив немного хитрости:

```
import json

text = """\
{"a": "ex1", "b": "ex2", "c": "ex3"}, 
{"a": "ex4", "b": "ex5", "c": "ex6"},
{"a": "exn-2", "b": "exn-1", "c": "exn"}
"""

data = json.loads('[' + text + ']')
print(type(data), len(data))

for row in data:
    print(row)
```

Результат:

```
<class 'list'> 3
{'a': 'ex1', 'b': 'ex2', 'c': 'ex3'}
{'a': 'ex4', 'b': 'ex5', 'c': 'ex6'}
{'a': 'exn-2', 'b': 'exn-1', 'c': 'exn'}
```

---

**PS.**
Литералы списка и словаря (ассоциативного массива) в питоне имеет совпадение с `json`, поэтому можно вместо json-декодера использовать `from ast import literal_eval` из соседнего ответа

Comment: 1- шаблон в вопросе не является литералом списка или словаря. Если SyntaxError исправить, то как tuple можно интерпретировать 2- если json может разпознать строку, то он более преподчтителен (более универсальный и быстрее скорее всего будет).

Answer (score 1):

Используя [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) можно легко искать нужный словарь/запись в списке словарей/записей:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

In [39]: df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads('[{}]'.format(text)))

In [40]: df
Out[40]:
       a      b    c
0    ex1    ex2  ex3
1    ex4    ex5  ex6
2  exn-2  exn-1  exn

In [41]: df.query("a=='ex1' and b=='ex2' and c=='ex3'")
Out[41]:
     a    b    c
0  ex1  ex2  ex3

In [42]: df.query("a=='ex1' and b=='ex2' and c=='ex3'").to_dict('records')
Out[42]: [{'a': 'ex1', 'b': 'ex2', 'c': 'ex3'}]

In [43]: df.query("a=='ex1' and b=='ex2' and c=='ex3'").to_dict('records')[0]
Out[43]: {'a': 'ex1', 'b': 'ex2', 'c': 'ex3'}
```

если не нужен DataFrame:

```
In [45]: (pd.DataFrame(yaml.safe_load('[{}]'.format(text)))
            .query("a=='ex1' and b=='ex2' and c=='ex3'")
            .to_dict('records')[0])
Out[45]: {'a': 'ex1', 'b': 'ex2', 'c': 'ex3'}
```