# Ввести словарь через input()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пожалуйста помогите разбираться. Я не понимаю как работать с dict(input()). У меня появляется такая ошибка

```
dict1 = dict(input())
print(dict1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python\Dictionary.py", line 2, in <module>
dict1 = dict(input())
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: Так а чего вы хотите? Вы вводите словарь в виде текста с клавиатуры?

Comment: А нельзя что ли??

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Парсинг строки в словарь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795975/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8c)

Comment: Нельзя конечно. Откуда питон должен знать, по какому правилу преобразовывать строку в словарь?

Comment: Но когда я пишу  
dict1 = dict(input().split())
print(dict1)

И введи в клавиатуру 14, то получается

{'1': '4'}

Comment: То есть вообще никак нельзя это сделать?

Comment: Сделать что? Какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: Ну ввести например 4 5 и питон это понял как {4: 5}

Comment: @CrazyElf так не работает, выше в комменте автор написал

Comment: Мне не нужно чтобы он 45 так понял, именно 4 5

Comment: Зато вот так заработает `dict([input().split()])`

Comment: Думаю я знаю как написать, спасибо вам ребята! Сейчас отвечу.

Comment: @andreymal сейчас и так попробую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем то, что я хотела, но тоже хорошо

```
dict1 = {}
key = int(input())
dict1[key] = input()
print(dict1)



4
5
{4: '5'}
```

Можно и так. Спасибо @andreymal. Просто так у меня и первая цифра и вторая идут как строки. А так как я написала, можно легко изменить.

```
dict1 = dict([input().split()])
print(dict1)
```